# Sublime Text 3 : Open folder in current project via command line

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

`subl .` opens a folder in a new window. How can I open it inside the current project that is already open in a window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `subl -a .` adds the folder to the current window.